# Can't use ghci-inferred type signature for function returning Sing (d :: Symbol)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to recover the `Symbol` used in the type of a value:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Temp where

import GHC.TypeLits

data Temp (d :: Symbol) (a :: *) where 
  T :: a -> Temp d a

{-
description :: SingI Symbol d => Temp d a -> Sing Symbol d
-}
description (_ :: Temp d a) = (sing :: Sing d)
```

This loads fine in `ghci` (version 7.6.1):

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l Temp
[1 of 1] Compiling Temp             ( Temp.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Temp.
*Temp> :t description
description :: SingI Symbol d => Temp d a -> Sing Symbol d
```

However, if I try to use the type inferred by `ghci` in the module itself (uncommenting the line in Temp.hs), I get the following error:

```
Temp.hs:14:16:
    `SingI' is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for `description':
      description :: SingI Symbol d => Temp d a -> Sing Symbol d
```

Which makes sense to me, since [`Sing` and `SingI` seem to take a single parameter in the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc//dist/current/docs/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0/GHC-TypeLits.html#t%3aSing).

What's the proper type signature for `description`?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the pretty-printer; seems like it shouldn't be pretty-printing inferred values of implicit kind arguments if you can't give those kind arguments explicitly!

Comment: I observed the same buggy display with `Nat`. I'd assumed it was trying to print a kind signature somehow, but incorrectly displaying an implicit kind argument makes more sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it through some monkeying about:

```
description :: SingI d => Temp d a -> Sing d
```

Looks like there's some funky rewriting going on, but good enough for now.